My command prompt stops responding after i try and open jupyter lab/ jupyter notebook through it, jupyter opens leaving prompt frozen
So i was following a youtube tutorial and needed to set my virtual environment for jupyter in my command prompt and when i write jupyter lab my command prompt stops responding and doesn't allow me to write anything because the next line doesn't work.
Even without setting the environment it does the same thing.
I installed the latest version of anaconda today after witnessing the same issue prior.
so when i type jupyter lab i get the following :-
jupyter lab
......
    To access the server, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/ACER/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-13908-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/lab?token=1a303eff345dbbeff2f77d03baa6184ba1fd8e066123d66f
        http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab?token=1a303eff345dbbeff2f77d03baa6184ba1fd8e066123d66f
[I 2024-08-04 16:17:24.382 ServerApp] Skipped non-installed server(s): bash-language-server, dockerfile-language-server-nodejs, javascript-typescript-langserver, jedi-language-server, julia-language-server, pyright, python-language-server, r-languageserver, sql-language-server, texlab, typescript-language-server, unified-language-server, vscode-css-languageserver-bin, vscode-html-languageserver-bin, vscode-json-languageserver-bin, yaml-language-server
0.01s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
[W 2024-08-04 16:17:31.348 LabApp] Could not determine jupyterlab build status without nodejs
[W 2024-08-04 16:17:32.163 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Forbidden'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\ACER\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1790, in _execute
        result = await result
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\ACER\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1790, in _execute
        result = await result
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\ACER\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\auth\decorator.py", line 73, in inner
        return await out
    
    KeyError: 'last_activity'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\ACER\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1790, in _execute
        result = await result
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\ACER\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\auth\decorator.py", line 73, in inner
        return await out
               ^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\ACER\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\services\kernels\handlers.py", line 41, in get
        kernels = await ensure_async(km.list_kernels())
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\ACER\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 521, in list_kernels
        model = self.kernel_model(kernel_id)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\ACER\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 507, in kernel_model
        "last_activity": isoformat(kernel.last_activity),
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\ACER\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 687, in __get__
        return t.cast(G, self.get(obj, cls))  # the G should encode the Optional
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\ACER\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 649, in get
        value = self._validate(obj, default)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\ACER\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 722, in _validate
        value = self.validate(obj, value)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\ACER\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 2311, in validate
        self.error(obj, value)
      File "C:\Users\ACER\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 831, in error
        raise TraitError(e)
    traitlets.traitlets.TraitError: The 'last_activity' trait of a ServerKernelManager instance expected a datetime, not the NoneType None.
[E 2024-08-04 16:17:40.077 ServerApp] {
      "Host": "localhost:8888",
      "Accept": "*/*",
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/lab/tree/Getting%20Started.ipynb?",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/127.0.0.0"
    }
[E 2024-08-04 16:17:40.079 ServerApp] 500 GET /api/kernels?1722777459980 (b55017e6aace4da0b117d7d7d9fbc16e@::1) 34.91ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab/tree/Getting%20Started.ipynb?
[I 2024-08-04 16:17:40.090 ServerApp] Kernel started: cd98396c-a478-4f2d-8930-49b1518cabf0
0.01s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
[I 2024-08-04 16:17:43.919 ServerApp] Connecting to kernel cd98396c-a478-4f2d-8930-49b1518cabf0.
[I 2024-08-04 16:17:43.940 ServerApp] Connecting to kernel cd98396c-a478-4f2d-8930-49b1518cabf0.
[I 2024-08-04 16:17:43.982 ServerApp] Connecting to kernel cd98396c-a478-4f2d-8930-49b1518cabf0.
[I 2024-08-04 16:19:40.125 ServerApp] Saving file at /Getting Started.ipynb
[W 2024-08-04 16:19:40.128 ServerApp] Notebook Getting Started.ipynb is not trusted

and my command prompt stops even though jupyter opened but this makes it harder to set a venv.
I have uninstalled and installed anaconda , i have removed parts of this error because stackoverflow wont let me ask my first ever question on this platform and instead says it 'appears' spam. Well looks like someone just had a Type 1 error.

That is exactly how jupyter works in terminal, the program is running and it does not return to the terminal prompt until you close it. No problems found here.

You can always open another terminal window if you need a terminal on your computer while you have a running server generating a Jupyter session. The beginning part of your post and title is about what Dr. Snoopy (and what I added) covers. You'd need to make a separate post focusing on your other issue. One thing I see is that you have two different things going on here. It looks like from AppData/Roaming/jupyter you installed Jupyter or Python aside from Anaconda and aren't using the Anaconda Navigator to run what you installed with Anaconda? Don't mix. That is a recipe for issues.
